# Regex to convert from epoch milliseconds to ISO8601 format?

Tags: regex, notepad++, date-formatting, epoch

Since I want to do this across a file which has lines beginning with milliseconds representing time series, I was looking for a good regex to use e.g., to make changes across a file or just from a bash shell. 
Options with `sed`, `awk` or with just bash and `printf` would help.
Any ideas ?

TIA.

Comment: This is not a job for a regular expression. This is a programming job.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for Npp + regex, here is a one liner perl script that does the job:

**Input file:**

```
cat file.txt
1234567890123 blah blah
1111111111456 blue blue
1212121212789 foo bar
```

**script:**

```
perl -MPOSIX -pnE 's/(\d+)\d{3}/POSIX::strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S",localtime $1)/e' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
2009.02.14 00:31:30 blah blah
2005.03.18 02:58:31 blue blue
2008.05.30 06:20:12 foo bar
```

Comment: I updated the question to be more command line/shell focused.